# What is the Rotation Matrix in PCA?

Tags: pca, rotation

I'm trying to implement th Local Coordinate System (LCS) of [this](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2502171) paper.

It's all clear to me about how it works, but the only thing that I' dont understand is the "rotation" mechanism. Quoting the paper (sect 4.2):

> This processing actually encompasses three distinct operations:
>   centering (C), **rotation with PCA basis (R)** and dimensionality
>   reduction by a factor of 2 (D).

I don't understand what is the bold part. And later:Later in the same section:

> we learn off-line (e.g., on Flickr60K for Holidays) a rotation matrix
>   Q_i from training descriptors mapped to this word.

I understand the sentence except for the "rotation matrix" part, again.

From my knowledge, PCA consists in obtaining two matrices: the eigenvector matrix of the covariance matrix of the centered data and the correspondent diagonal eigenvalues matrix. I know that if we want to have a `nxp` matrix and we want to reduce a vector `v` from `1xp` to `1xd` (where `d<p`) all we have to do is the product between `v` and the `pxd` diagonal matrix of the most relevant eigenvalues.  But I've never heard the "rotation" stuff.

Can someone please explain me this?

Comment: Rotation matrix = eigenvector matrix. You should read some intuitive explanations of PCA where "rotation" is made explicit, see e.g. my answer in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691 and perhaps some other answers there too.

Comment: Almost surely they mean eigenvector matrix. PCA _is_ orthogonal rotation.

Comment: @amoeba Oh I see! Is it correct that when we perform dimension reduction of v what we do is the product of v by the eigenvalue matrix obtain by PCA? Here instead seems that we have to multiply v by the eigenvector matrix!

Comment: No. What you wrote in your post after "I know that" is wrong. You always multiply with eigenvectors (which is the same as rotating).

Comment: @amoeba Ok I understand. One last thing (I don't think I need to open another question for it). Since eigenvectors are ordered according to the most significant eigenvalues, do I have to order `v` in the same way to before doing the product with the eigenvector matrix? For example, if the third eigenvectors is swapped with the first one, do I have to swap `v[3]` with `v[1]` before doing the product with eigenvector matrix?

Comment: No you don't need to swap. This question shows that you have very little understanding of PCA, so I would strongly recommend you to do some basic reading on it.